# unsure how to calculate power spectral density after passing through low pass filter

Tags: filter, noise, low-pass

[image][image]

Unsure how to answer this question any help would be greatly appreciated
i have uploaded my attempt at an answer however i feel that i have done the conversion from dBm to Watts incorrectly
Im also unsure how to determine the power output of the filter

Comment: Hi Josh! It's really hard to help someone who doesn't tell us where they're stuck – an answer could totally explain what you need to know to solve such questions in the future, or it could totally lie off what you need to know. That's why we don't answer homework questions without an attempt of the asker! So, please, describe in detail what you tried so far, and what *your **own**, specific question* is that you need an answer to to get closer to solving your exercise.

Comment: thanks Marcus i will edit it and upload my attempt. Im suck on how to calculate the power of the noise after passing through this filter. I understand that the power output is (PSD of noise)*(|H(f)|^2) however i do not know how to apply this to the question asked as the power is given per Hz and the frequency response of the filter is in MHz

Comment: Do proceed with uploading your attempt.  But note that 1MHz = \$10^6\$ Hz.  So everywhere something in your calculation says "MHz" you can substitute in "1000000 Hz" and do the math to get everthing into Hz.  (Or, conversely, you can substitute 0.000001 MHz = 1Hz, and you should get exactly the same result).

Comment: thanks yeah i was wondering if the power of the output is multipied by the frequency. so for the interval 0<f<20MHz is the output power = -90*20MHz*|H(f)|^2.